# Citrix cloud with VMware on premises login issue

Tags: citrix

Esporadically login errors occurred when I'm trying to sign in to citrix cloud(aprox 40% of the attempts). My citrix cloud have configured two on-premises cloud connectors on windows 2019 domain members, this cloud connectors has two interfaces one for OOB and the other for internet(different vlans). Dns is provided by AD server. Event viewer and citrix connection tests on the cloud connectors shows everything OK, no errors. I'm asking some help to debug the problem.